# How do I display a 64bit unsigned integer with sprintf?

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm displaying a 32bit timer value on my putty-console. The timer includes the time in microseconds since startup of my stm32wb55. With following code, it works exaclty like I want:

`uint32_t time_micro32`

```
sprintf((char*)buf,
          "Time: %lu \r\n",
         (time_micro32));
```

But now, I want to display the time in 64bit resolution with `uint64_t time_micro64`. I tried many, but nothing works. Can anybody help me, please? I´m programming in STM32CubeIDE

Comment: Why would you use microsecond resolution and then print it with some PC programming stdio.h barf that at best has millisecond resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I´m programming in STM32CubeIDE

So you are using most probably using newlib in it's "nano" version - a smaller version of newlib, which does not handle printing 64-bit variables.

Link with full newlib version (or use other C standard library) and the code will work fine. Search your gui - there should be an option like "use -nano version of the standard library" or "pass -specs=nano.specs to the compiler". Uncheck that option. Make sure that `-lnano` nor `-specs=nano.specs` or similar options are not passed to the compiler. After that, you can use `%llu` or `"%"PRIu64`.

Prefer to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

> Are there any other options?

Roll your own implementation that would convert 64-bit variable into a string - writing such function is very trivial. Then use this function and print the resulting string. I have [such function](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/-/blob/master/libs/libc/src/printex.c#L43).

Comment: Switching the Runtime library from `specs=nano.specs` to `standard C library` was the key! Thank you!

Comment: "After that you can use %llu or "%"PRIu64." --> sounds good today. Later on when, with `long long` as 128-bit, using `%llu` with `uint64_t` will fail.  Best to print with `"%"PRIu64`.

Comment: Linked function looks wrong.  Rather than `div_t d = div(v, 10);`, I'd expect `lldiv_t d = lldiv(v, 10);`.  But that remains insufficient when `v > LLONG_MAX`.  Hopefully only `c = v % 10;` path is used.  Note: `llabs(LLONG_MIN)` is UB.