# The variable I'm trying to pint print the wrong value

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller

Im reading a sensor values and saving them in the following variables.

```c
uint16_t C2;

uint16_t C4;

signed long int dT = 0;
```

Then I want to make this calculation;

```c
signed long long int OFF = 0;

OFF=C2* 131072+(C4*dT)/64;
```

And when I print OFF it prints 0.

I think the problem is because dT it's a 32bit and OFF it's a 64bit. But I don't know how to solve this.

I'm using stm32f103rb and programing in stm32CubeIDE

Comment: Which language is this - C or C#? I think, either way, `(C4*dT)/64` will often give zero, as it is integer division.

Comment: You haven't posted what the values are in `C2` and `C4`.  How can anyone tell you what's wrong if you don't post complete information?

Comment: How do you print it? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153770/how-do-i-display-a-64bit-unsigned-integer-with-sprintf/66154865#66154865 answer your quesiton?

Comment: Give us a specific example that doesn't work, with concrete values for `C2` and `C4`.

Comment: print all the values c2, c4 & dt first

Comment: dT=362759 C2=32705 and C4=20738

Comment: OFF is -24930011 on 32 bit system. The problem is in printing

Comment: Why is it OFF-24930011

Comment: Because you overflow signed integer values

Answer (score 0):

If you do not cast and execute on 32 bit system the result is -24930011

If you cast

```
    OFF=(int64_t)C2*131072+((int64_t)C4*dT)/64;
```

the result is 4404255012.

https://godbolt.org/z/eEab1dr1d

Comment: OFF=(uint64_t)C2*131072+((uint64_t)C4*dT)/64;   

sprintf((char*)buf, "teste OFF %lu \r\n", OFF);    
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf),10);   

And it prints:    
C2 (32705)     
C4 (20738)     
dT (203190)     
    
OFF 57582373

Comment: @Marias `%lu` is for long unsigned which is 32 bit not 64 bits

Comment: I've declared OFF as uint64_t but the print still prints wrong.

uint64_t OFF = 0;          OFF=(uint64_t)C2*131072+((uint64_t)C4*dT)/64;       sprintf((char*)buf, "teste OFF %lu \r\n", OFF);
               HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf),10);
               HAL_Delay(1000);                And it print:      C2 (32705)    
C4 (20738)    
dT (188475)    

OFF 52814253

Comment: I can't use %llu, because then it will only print me lu and no value

Comment: @Marias and you think that using "lu" will sort things out? It will not you need to write your own function.

Comment: Actually using %llu resolved the probelm, I only had to configure Runtime library from specs=nano.specs to standard C library